# Wrap chartlet title text when using a grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

Example to illustrate:

```
library(tidyverse)

diamonds2 <- diamonds  

long_names <- c("very long label blah blah", "another long label look at that",
                "some text here big long label", "and so on and so forth", "the quick brown fox")

diamonds2$long <- long_names

ggplot(diamonds2, aes(x = depth, y = carat)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(long))
```

Looks like this:
[image]

I would like to wrap the titles of each chartlet so that all of the text can be read.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
diamonds2$long <- long_names %>% str_wrap(width = 10)
```

...and then ggplot as before:

[image]